# How to check the number of workers running inside a docker container of kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, flask, kubernetes, uwsgi

I am using Flask-uWSGI architecture for a production service and have set the `master` flag of uWSGI config as `False`. While running the service, I pass NUM_WORKERS of uWSGI as `2` to the docker container. Based on this [doc on uWSGI config](https://www.techatbloomberg.com/blog/configuring-uwsgi-production-deployment/), `master` flag is necessary to re-spawn and pre-fork workers. I wonder if my service containers within the pods are actually using 2 workers?

So, I want to `exec` into a pod and see the number of uWSGI workers which are actually being used?

Not related but my uWSGI config:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 0.0.0.0:9999
protocol = http
module = my_app.server.wsgi
callable = app
master = false
thunder-lock = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a prometheus-exporter to your app, and curl `/metrics` endpoint manually:
https://github.com/timonwong/uwsgi_exporter

It has num workers metric: https://github.com/timonwong/uwsgi_exporter/blob/9f88775cc1a600e4038bb1eae5edfdf38f023dc4/exporter/exporter.go#L50

Further, you can collect this using Prometheus to monitor and alert automatically.

Comment: I already have prometheus setup to my app and it has some latency and log related metrics.

Comment: then try exec and `curl http://127.0.0.1/metrics | grep workers`